# Cant find theme HOLO in Android Layout editor

Tags: android, eclipse, android-theme

I am facing a strange problem with Eclipse. I cant find HOLO theme in Android's Layout Editor. When I click on the dropbox item "Holo", I can't find any themes inside that. I don't know what made this problem occur. Editor keep showing the error "Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?". I tried different versions of Eclipse. But problem still exists. I have also tried creating a new project. But no luck. Do you guys have any idea about solving this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The holo theme (as far as I know) is declared in the manifest not the layout editor

Comment: Thanks. That I know, I can see the theme when I run the app. But the problem is with xml editor.

Comment: Oh I see. I had this problem I could not get it fixed. But then my PC crashed and I reformatted it and the new ADT bundle did not do that anymore. Good luck.